# jenkins: How to eval parameter value based on other parameters

Tags: parameters, continuous-integration, jenkins

I want to create a jenkins job that will have the following parameters definition:

```
iteration=13
folder_name=iter_${iteration}
```

I want that during runtime folder_name will get it's value based on the value of iteration.

Unfortunately, it seems like Jenkins does not eval values of parameters based on another parameter.

Do you know of a good plugin that can do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try the [EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin). Try to set up a new build step where you put the second variable:

> folder_name=iter_${iteration}

I'm not 100% sure that this works, though.